# How to set up Facebook App Events for React Native Expo?

Tags: react-native, facebook, expo

I'm trying to use Facebook App Events with Expo. These are the steps I've taken:

```
expo install expo-facebook
```

Then in my navigation page I imported this:

```
import * as Facebook from 'expo-facebook';
```

Then in my NavigationContainer onStateChange function if the screen name changes, I trigger these functions:

```
await Facebook.initializeAsync({ appId: 'myAppId', appName: "myAppName" });
await Facebook.logEventAsync(currentRouteName);
```

When I create a simulation build and run the app and switch between screens, the events aren't logged with my Facebook Developer account.

What am I doing wrong? Or is everything right and this just won't work unless the app is opened in a Facebook app browser?

I have a client that wants to run ads for iOS for app install conversions and they say this would allow them to do that.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, I've tried absolutely everything, and it looks like there is a problem with a library. Check this issue - https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/14278 .

Comment: I ended up publishing the app to the app store to see what would happen. Some basic events are showing up like app installs and some activity in the app. I'm not sure if everything is set up right, but there are some extra options now in the Facebook Events Manager page that helps you set up events. 

I made a video on my experience here: https://youtu.be/hEXMVTVdsrw

Maybe it is an issue with the library like you said. If you publish the app, you may be able to do more after the app is already live on the app store. In the video, you can see what I saw after publishing it.